# Why is my HTML not rendering when modifying a text node?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Is there a way to modify a DOM text node like this:

```
node.nodeValue = "foo <strong> bar </strong>"
```

and have it correctly render the HTML? Thanks.

Comment: Would node.innerHTML do this?

Comment: What is `node`? If it's a text node need to look to replace it or wrap it or something so it would even take html. nodeValue is not appropriate for html

Comment: A quick test shows that it does work fine on text nodes. Are you sure it's a text node you want to modify, and that the example in your post is indeed the result you want to see? Obviously you can't insert an element in a text node.

Comment: @aidanharris Only if `node` was an element.

Comment: Sorry for not being more specific: node is a DOM element eventually reached by walking to that node. In this particular case, it's a text element.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a specific node (of type #text) and want to change its value you can use the nodeValue property:

```
node.nodeValue="foo <strong> bar </strong>";
```

Note:

innerText (and possibly textContent) will return/set both the current node and all descendent nodes text, and so may not be the behaviour you want/expect.

If node value is not set to #text node then below will work for you

```
node.innerHTML="foo <strong> bar </strong>";
```

Refere below url for ref :

Node Description    https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeValue

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! Suppose, though, that the node type was of type 3, or a text node. the innerHTML method doesn't seem to modify anything, but nodeValue does. Is there a different method I could use?

Comment: @MarvinMichaels use what is appropriate for the nodeType. Not hard to keep track and there are only so many types

Comment: @Marvin :- Thats what i mentioned in my answer if your node type is 3 then use nodeValue if it is not then use innerHTML.

Comment: @TanviB right, but is there a way to use nodeValue and have it render in HTML? Right now, the nodeValue autoescapes and doesn't render it in the page.

Comment: @charlietfl thanks, but what is appropriate for nodeValue that renders the HTML accurately?

Comment: @MarvinMichaels same as mentioned in numerous comments `innerHTML`